# Which event do you use for instant detecting cursor over element when you scroll fast?

Tags: javascript, dom

I noticed that events like wheel or mouseover aren't fired when i scroll fast over element. What do you use in this case?

I tried to use wheel and mouseover events

Comment: You probably won't get these, so you will have to check yourself. Store the current `clientX` and `clientY` and compare it to the bounding boxes of elements you want to check during scroll, that seems the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you could try to compute where the last position is in relation to your elements while scrolling. Simply store the last `clientX` and `clientY`, and compare whether that point touches one of your targets on scroll. Also add the `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` event listeners because we're toggling a class here we want to remove when the mouse isn't over it regardless of scrolling.

```js
function pointInBBox( x, y, element ){
    
  const bb = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // Check if the [x,y] point is inside the DOMRect() bounding box.
  return x >= bb.left
    && x <= bb.left + bb.width
    && y >= bb.top
    && y <= bb.top + bb.height;
  
}

const targets = [...document.querySelectorAll( '.target' )];

let x = 0, y = 0, currentTarget;

// This will store the x and y position of the mouse
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', event => {
  
  x = event.clientX;
  y = event.clientY;
  
});

document.addEventListener( 'scroll', event => {
   
   // Find the first element that the mouse is over (for efficiency)
   const mouseIsOver = targets.find(div => pointInBBox( x, y, div ));
   
   // Remove the class from the last target if one exists
   if( currentTarget ) currentTarget.classList.remove( 'mouse-over' );
   // Add the class to the new target if it exists
   if( mouseIsOver ) mouseIsOver.classList.add( 'mouse-over' );
   // Assign the target so we can remove the class later
   currentTarget = mouseIsOver;
   
});

targets.forEach(target => {
  
  // Make sure we add the class in regular non-scrolling mode as well
  target.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', event => {

    if( currentTarget ) currentTarget.classList.remove( 'mouse-over' );
  
    currentTarget = target;
    currentTarget.classList.add( 'mouse-over' );

  });
  // And the same here, remove the class if the mouse leaves when we're not scrolling
  target.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', event => {

    if( target === currentTarget ) currentTarget = null;

    target.classList.remove( 'mouse-over' );

  });

})
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.target { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: flex; }
.target:after { content: 'mouse in here'; margin: auto; font-size: 50px; color: white; text-shadow: 0 0 20px black; opacity: 0; }
.target.mouse-over:after { opacity: 1; transition: opacity .2s; }
```

```html
<div class="target" style="background:red"></div>
<div class="target" style="background:orange"></div>
<div class="target" style="background:yellow"></div>
<div class="target" style="background:green"></div>
<div class="target" style="background:teal"></div>
<div class="target" style="background:blue"></div>
<div class="target" style="background:purple"></div>
<div class="target" style="background:magenta"></div>
```